# How do I create a WorkbookOpen event for every workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

How can I create an event that fires whenever a workbook is opened? I want a generic event for any workbook, rather than embed something in each workbook to be run once opened.

I can access the application object using this:

```
var xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application)ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there?
This kind of thing seems possible to do this in VBA:

```vb
Private WithEvents app As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = Application
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If Not Win_Toggle = 1 Then Exit Sub

    With app
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Left = -500
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You should cast to `Application` instead of `_Application`, and you'll have access to the events you're looking for...

```
var xlApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
xlApp.WorkbookOpen += XlAppOnWorkbookOpen;

private void XlAppOnWorkbookOpen(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb)
{
    // ...
}
```